# Android Wi-Fi Direct: re-connect to a device without re-Discovery

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, discovery, wifip2p

I know how Wi-Fi Direct works and what is the Discovery phase, because i read the entire Wi-Fi Direct specification v1.1.

When i want to connect to a device in Android, i must start the discovery phase. When onPeersAvailable in triggered, i can connect to one of these peers.
Now i want to disconnect and re-connect quickly to the same peer, without to re-execute the discovery.
This scenario is possible? For example saving channel information and using java reflection to set the channel and start quickly the connection?

I know, it's a strage question :)

Comment: mm ok, probably is not possibile :( because android uses wpa_supplicant.
In wpa_supplicant, you need to restart p2p_find when you need to connect to a peer.

Answer (score 1):

its valid question, and it appears that when starting the connection, the connected device must be on current discovered peers list, and it is is not, then the connection requests will fail. Thus you can do the connection only after proper discovery.